# how to handle async response as validation error in formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have this code.

```js
export const PostcodeFinder: React.FC = () => {
  const {
    postcodeSearch,
    isLoading,
    data,
    isPending,
    error: fetchError,
  } = usePostcodeSearch();


  return (
    <Formik
      validate={(values) => {
        // will be ran before the `fetchError` is set from async response
        if (fetchError) {
          return { postcode: fetchError };
        }

        return {};
      }}
```

The problem is that validate is called onChange or when the form is submitted so it runs before the async response has returned.

How can I set the validation error from an async response in formik?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a promise which will resolve to errors object `{ someKey: 'some message' }`

```
<Formik
      validate={async (values) => {
        const resp = fetch(`/validateEmailExists?email=${values.email}`);
        const data = await resp.json();
        if (data.emailExists) {
          return { email: data.message /* it can be your own custom message */ };
        }

        return {};
      }}
```

Comment: that seems the wrong place to put the call.  How is data then used by the rest of the form

Comment: this data is nit data about form, I just named it data which is actually a response from api which is only being used in this validate function

Comment: You have not share your whole story, what is that async thing in your validate function?